# Eclipse: Ctrl + Shift + ? hotkeys in Linux / KDE?

Tags: linux, eclipse, hotkeys

I've recently installed Eclipse Helios (Java Developers Edition, vanilla from [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org)) on my Arch Linux/KDE 4 machine to aid navigation in a large Java project. The problem is, many key bindings in Eclipse tend to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> as a modifier, and this is the same combination I use to switch keyboard layouts. Thus, if I press, say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, I see no Open Type dialog; Cyrillic 'e' is just inserted into the editor (this is the same as if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd>).

I know I can change the key bindings (both for Eclipse and for the layout switcher), but maybe someone knows the way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> working in a setup similar to mine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround (involving changing the key bindings in Eclipse, but in a way you might not have considered) is described in [bug 239690](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239690):

> I've found the workaround for the Eclipse 3.4.
>   Just binding the corresponding hotkey in the russian layout to the same command.
>
> For example, for the Save command.
>   `Menu Window -> Preferences -> Keys`, find "`Save`", press "`Copy command`", switch
>   to the russian layout and press the desired key combination in the "`Binding`" field (that was `Ctrl+&#1067;` in my case of the standard keyboard and windows - cp1251 layout)

More generally, that issue of hotkeys/keyboard layout is tracked in [bug 61190](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=61190), and a patch has recently been submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yeah I suspected it is SWT/GTK bug, looks like it has a long history. The first solution sounds interesting; I'll probably go this way.